# Draw a color chooser like Fresh Paint

Tags: algorithm, graphics, colors, android-canvas

I like the look of the color circle of Fresh Paint, and would like to clone it in my incoming project. However, I cannot find the pattern of the HSV or RGB distribution of the circle. Here is an example:

[image]

I guess the slider at the right is for H value from 0 to 360. But I have no idea how to make the circle with that H value. Please give me the formula/pattern of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen this in action, but it looks like they're using chroma rather than saturation, and have mapped lightness and chroma to (sort-of) polar co-ordinates. So the chroma varies with the distance from the center and the value/brightness varies with the y-coordinate.

Essentially the result is that the middle of the circle is bright, fully saturated colour, and the edge is a greyscale. Colours are linearly interpolated from center to edge.

I originally thought this might be straight polar co-ordinates, but I suspect it's been simplified to just use y instead of the angle.

Essentially, the de-saturated greyscale at the edge is a linear white to black gradient, top to bottom (not varying with angle as a polar co-ordinate would). The colour at the center is a saturated colour chosen with the hue selector at the side, and then all colours in between are linearly interpolated.

So in pseudo-code:

```
let x, y be points in the circle, range -1 to 1.
let red, grn, blu be the center colour value.
let lerp(a, b, t) = (a * (1 - t) + b * t)

r = sqrt(x * x + y *y)               // calculate radial co-ordinate
                                     // reject points r > 1 (outside circle)
grey_value = (y + 1) / 2             // calculate de-saturated value, 0 to 1.
final_red = lerp(red, grey_value, r) // lerp the RGB from the center to the edge.
final_grn = lerp(grn, grey_value, r)
final_blu = lerp(blu, grey_value, r)
```

Obviously thats not particularly optimal and won't draw nice anti-aliased edges. It would probably be much faster to pre-calculate a texture with a greyscale gradient, and an alpha mask based on 'r', which can be alpha-blended on top of a flat-coloured circle.

Comment: I have no knowledge about the graphic color, just very basic about RGB, but not HSV. Can you please explain more details about color `chroma` and `linear interpolated`?

Comment: To be honest if you just want to read up on colour models, wikipedia is fine: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

Comment: As for linear interpolation - that's not strictly related to color. It's just the name for calculating values between two points, by drawing a straight line between them. Again, wikipedia has more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation In your case the two points are the center of the circle and the edge, and linear interpolation would give you any point in between. You would not necessarily draw your circle this way, it's just a way of describing how the values might be calculated.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try implementing this. Will answer if get any progress :)

Comment: I've revised my answer with a little bit more detail, and a slight change - I don't think it's fully polar co-ordinates.

Comment: Okay, you gave me the idea. I have the graphic designer draw a mask and blend it with the plain color, and it works, and the performance is good too :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like the Y axis is lightness, with bottom being black and top being white, and the X axis is saturation, with the center being fully saturated and each edge being fully desaturated. Of course this gives you a square, so you need to map this to a circle. Enter the fine people at math: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103660/homeomorphism-from-square-to-unit-circle